# Stopping .bat files dynamically using java

Tags: java, batch-file, command-line

I need to write a Java app in which I have several `.bat` files which run in continuous loops. I have 4 of them, and only one of them can run at one time. I need to stop the other 3.

Something like

`if` *`condition`*

- stop the other 3 `.bat` files ( well normally one of them would run but not knowing which, I try to stop all 3);
- start the `.bat` file which satisfies the condition.
- when other condition of a different `.bat` file is satisfied, the other 3 (again, one actually) would be stopped + this `.bat` file starts running (continuous loop)

I am struggling to get to how to stop these `.bat` files from my java code... is there anything that I can use in command line to stop one particular `.bat` file from running, identifying it by name or something? Because running commands from `cmd` using Java is something that I know how to do.

Comment: Do you run these bat files from the same java application?

Comment: yes, same application. I did something like this using a Raspi + Shell Scripts..I want to duplicate so to say what I did there.

Runtime rtLeft = Runtime.getRuntime();
   rtLeft.exec("sudo killall middle.sh");

I need something similar

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for delay: I was very busy.

Generally when you execute external process from java (ether using `Runtime.exec()` or `ProcessBuilder`) you get reference to instance of `java.lang.Process` that has method `destroy()`. Calling this method is equivalent to `kill -9 PID` in Unix.